# ubuntu initdb error file <dir>/share/postgresql/postgres.bki does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

initdb: file "*user*/share/postgresql/postgres.bki" does not exist
This might mean you have a corrupted installation or identified the
wrong directory with the invocation option -L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The installation directory should be correct
2. Installation should have completed successfully -- no aborting or memory or network errors.

If all else is well, you can copy the bki file from another installation.